# internel server error (Error returned whilst using the OMDB API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, backend

I am trying to retrieve data using the OMDB API & keep being presented with 'internel server error' despite my data request:
res.send(results["search"][0]) **(Please note that I am using the goorm IDE)**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");

app.get("/results", function(req, res){

    request("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=california&apikey=thewdb", function(error, response, body){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(body);
            res.send(results["search"][0]);
        }
    });
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Property_names) in javascript are strings and they are case sensitive.

The response from OMDB is in `Search` field not `search`, so it should be

```
res.send(results["Search"][0]);
```

Comment: Hi Rami, Thats great! everything is working now. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

```
app.get("/results", (req, res) => {
    request("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=california&apikey=thewdb", (error, response, body) => {
        (!error && response.statusCode == 200) ?
            res.send(JSON.parse(body).Search[0])
            :
            res.send({ err: error });
    });
});
```